# Receiving two errors that I can't seem to solve

Tags: c++

The idea of this bit of code is to store a word in a character vector and swap the letters around:

```
void scrambleWords(vector<string>& words, vector<char>& scramWord)
{
  string scram;
  char randChar;

  //get random value
  srand(time(0));
  int randNumWords = (rand() % 5 - 0);

  //choose word from vector based on random value
  scram = words.at(randNumWords);

  //put each letter into char vector
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < scram.size(); j++)
  {
    scram.at(j) = scramWord.push_back; //non-standard syntax; use '&' to 
    // Screate pointer for member AND '=' unable to resolve function overload
  }

  //get another random value, find random char within char vector, place at 
  end of vector
  for (unsigned int k = 0; k < scramWord.size(); k++)
  {
    int randNumScram = (rand() % scramWord.size() - 0);
    randChar = scramWord.at(randNumScram);
    scramWord.push_back(randChar);
  }
}
```

The error messages are inside the first for loop.

I've tried to solve this using information from my textbook as well as online.

Still can't seem to figure it out. Am I being overly complex for what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks.

Comment: `scram.at(j) = scramWord.push_back;` Well `push_back` is a member function, you can't assign it to to a `char&`, which is what `scram.at(j)` returns. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: From the comment above the loop, you probably mean `scramWord.push_back(scram.at(j));`.

Comment: @BoPersson That fixed it. Much appreciated.